# Limit of an integral that arose in Fourier Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, improper-integrals, complex-integration

$$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\delta}\frac{\sin(\alpha x) \sin(\lambda\alpha x)}{x^2}dx$$ where $\lambda,\delta \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda,\delta > 0$. Appreciate your help in finding this limit. I stumbled upon this when i am trying to solve [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/187215/14414) which is a part of this [bigger picture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/186158/14414). Appreciate your general comments/suggestions on these as well.

Answer (score 4):

Let $I(\alpha,\lambda)$ be the value of the integral. The change of variable $\alpha\,x=t$ gives
$$
I(\alpha,\lambda)=\alpha\int_0^{\delta\alpha}\frac{\sin t\sin(\lambda\,t)}{t^2}\,dt.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\frac{I(\alpha,\lambda)}{\alpha}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t\sin(\lambda\,t)}{t^2}\,dt=\frac{\pi}{2}\min(\lambda,1).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have a small request, just I realized that The denominator in integral is $x$ instead of $x^2$. Please hint me of an answer in this case.

Comment: In that case the integral is equal to $$\int_0^{\delta\alpha}\frac{\sin t\sin(\lambda\,t)}{t}\,dt$$ and converges to $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t\sin(\lambda\,t)}{t}\,dt=\frac14\log\frac{(\lambda+1)^2}{(\lambda-1)^2}.$$